# Yii2 advanced logging

Tags: logging, yii2

I need advanced log system for YII2 web-app.

In my apps models (extends from base active record model) I need on specific model methods logging this actions in DB.

For example, I need log in DB info about create/update/delete model. But one of model attributes - count of views. So when I update only this attr.  - we don't need log this action.

In my log table I need to insert next fields: model name, modelId, time, userId. Also, in future I want set in array list of logged methods, and on base model check list, and if method exist in this array - write log action into DB.

How can I realize this functional? I try working with magick method __call on AR base model, but its works only if called method have private or protected scopes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to implement it as model behavior and specify in which cases it should (/not) leave traces.

Check out [bedezign/yii2-audit](https://github.com/bedezign/yii2-audit), [nineinchnick/yii2-audit](https://github.com/nineinchnick/yii2-audit) extensions. Most probably, the can solve your problem out-of-box, otherwise they will bring you inspiration to write your own.